# How to use instance file in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLalchemy to create my db in flask. For this I create a project.db file and run the following code :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# create the extension
db = SQLAlchemy()
# create the app
app = Flask(__name__)
# configure the SQLite database, relative to the app instance folder
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///project.db"
# initialize the app with the extension
db.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

When I run create_table, it creates me a new folder named *instance* and a new project.db file in it. The result is that my first project.db does not work and is useless.

What must I do then ? Because when looking at different topic and videos this never happens. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `project.db` located? Keep it in the same folder as the script, or try using an absolute path like this?

`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////absolute/path/to/project.db"`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply ! 
Yes it is and doing this works but do you know if it is a good thing to "force it" to be there ? 
Because I had thought to do that but because flask was automatically moving the database to instance I was wondering if it was supposed to be done or if it was not.

Comment: Usually better to keep the database file in a consistent and predictable location, rather than relying on Flask to automatically move it to the instance folder. Makes navigation and management easier.